# Simulate connection problems in container

Tags: networking, docker, alpine-linux

I am debugging an issue with application which connects to RabbitMQ.
So I have docker-compose file with 2 containers: my app and RebbitMQ.

I would like to see what is going on if there are serious connection problems.

My first idea was to `exec` to docker container running rabbit and type:

> ifconfig eth0 down

Unfortunately this is not allowed in containers and i get: Permission denied.

What other options do I have? (currently RabbitMQ is alpine-based so there are not much tools pre-installed but I can easily switch my test RabbitMQ container to another distro).

Comment: If the containers are set up with the same network group, can you not just bring down the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a special container between RabbitMQ and my app called [muxy](https://github.com/mefellows/muxy):

There are different kinds of so called "[midleware](https://github.com/mefellows/muxy#middleware)" which you can add to this proxy in order to simulate different kinds of network problems.